# reading specific columns from excel file and writing to another excel file

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

My objective is to read an excel file columns and write it to another new file.
Till now I am able to create a new file with specified columns.I am able to read an excel file based on row and column index. But my objective is a different.
I have to pick specific columns from the excel file and write all the data to another file under the same column.
How can I achieve this.

```
require 'spreadsheet'

    #Step 1 : create an excel sheet

    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet = book.create_worksheet
    sheet.row(0).concat %w[id column_1 column_2 column_3]
    book.write 'Data/write_excel.xls'

    #step 2 : read the data excel file

    book1 = Spreadsheet.open('Data/read_excel.xls')
    sheet1 = book1.worksheet('')
    val = sheet1[0, 1]
    puts val
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option, knowing before the number of the source column and the number of the destination column:

```
# Step 3 copy the columns

col_num = 3 #=> the destination column
row_num = 1 #=> to skip the headers and start from the second row
sheet1.each row_num do |row|
    sheet[row_num, col_num] = row[0] # row[1] the number represents the column to copy from the source file
    row_num += 1
end
```

Then save the file: `book.write 'filename'`

Comment: Can we use column names here??

Comment: I don't think headers are supported, maybe you want to take a look to [documentation](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet). Anyway, you can build your headers using a hash like this: `sheet.row(0).map.with_index.with_object({}) { |(col, idx), h| h[col] = idx }`